# If else with ajax call wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

anyone can tell me why this wont work? It does work when i dont use a if else statement so im a bit stunned atm, i am using a html5 player where the play/pause button toggles, it needs to include the ajax watching when playing and stop watching when paused.  thnx

```
<script>
var test = 0;

if (test == 0) {
    $("#play").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "start_watching.php", 
            success: function(result){
                $("#fix").html(result);
            }
        });
   )}; 
   test = 1;
} else if (test == 1) {
    $("#play").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "stop_watching.php", 
            success: function(result){
                $("#fix").html(result);
            }
        });
   )}; 
   test = 2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Uhm, `test` is always `0` when the condition runs, you probably want to check for that ***inside*** the event handler

Comment: i make it change the condition at the end of the if? that not the way to do this?

Comment: No, that's not the way to do this

Comment: The `if` only runs once, when the page first loads.

Comment: So would making 2 separeted if's fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really verbose example of how to solve the logic, with the conditions inside the event handler

```
var test = 0, 
    url;

$("#play").click(function(){
    if (test === 0) {
        url  = "start_watching.php";
        test = 1;
    } else {
        url  = "stop_watching.php";
        test = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url     : url, 
        success : function(result){
           $("#fix").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you are a LIFE saver! ive been fighting nearly 2 days, and this solved it all!  +1